# iPhone. Open application during call

Tags: iphone

Is there any way to do this?

In other words, is it possible during a call to allow the user to open a certain application? (for example, to provide information based on the person who is calling).

If not, will something like this be available on iOS 4?

Comment: Note that any information on iOS 4 is under NDA until at least June 21.

Answer (score 0):

You can open an application during a call (not automatically).
User can press the home button (the one that is under the screen) during a call and open some third party application.

Another issue is to retrieve the contact that the user is talking to now - I believe that this is impossible.

Regarding iOS 4 - I am pretty sure that this will be possible...

Comment: I know you can do that. I was hoping there was a more automated way.

So there is no way to retrieve which call is currently active??????????? Any info on that on iOS4?

Comment: There is no way to do what you need in the current OS version. I haven't discovered the iOS 4 yet, so I can't help you on that.

Answer (score 0):

No.

AFAIK, there are two ways to launch an application:

- The user taps the icon
- The user responds to a push notification

You cannot directly control when your app is launched. Furthermore, once your app is running, there is no way to access information about the current call.

Comment: yes i probably didn't explain it properly. I would like the user to be able to have a faster way of opening the application rather than pressing home button -> go to the app and tap.
So, as i asked above, there is no way to retrieve which call is currently active??????????? Any info on that on iOS4?